# How to sort my sql statement by products as well as report a quantity

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to perform the query that will answer the following question:
"What products in what quantity were ordered in May 2004? Report by quantity ordered sorted for each product in descending order"

So far, I have successfully retrieved the list of all products ordered in May 2004. However, I do not know how to sort it for each product. I tried a group by expression (group by PRODUCTNAME) and got the error " Not a GROUP BY expression" (I had added "GROUP BY PRODUCTNAME" to the end of the working query below.)

Here is the working query I have up to this point:

```
SELECT ORDERS.ORDERNUMBER, PRODUCTS.PRODUCTNAME, ORDERS.SHIPPEDDATE
FROM ORDERS,
     PRODUCTS
WHERE SHIPPEDDATE LIKE '%MAY-04';
```

Here is an image of my output:[image: Output from working query above]

so the question is this: How do I perform this part of the query? "Report by quantity ordered sorted for each product in descending order"

Comment: That result is probably not what you want - you need a JOIN condition!

Comment: I am new to sql and am trying to teach myself. Feel free to comment or post a better query if you know of a better way. I am the ultimate beginner! lol

Comment: Is SHIPPEDDATE a string (varchar2), or a proper date column? It really should be a date, and there are better ways to do you filter for dates - you're currently implicitly converting it to a string and rely on your your session's NLS_DATA_FORMAT settings to find a match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, do proper joins, then add a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT o.ORDERNUMBER, p.PRODUCTNAME, SUM(od.quantity)
FROM ORDERS o
  JOIN order_details od ON o.ORDERNUMBER= od.ORDERNUMBER
  JOIN PRODUCTS p ON od.ProductCode = p.ProductCode
WHERE SHIPPEDDATE LIKE '%MAY-04'
GROUP BY o.ORDERNUMBER, p.PRODUCTNAME
```

I don't know Oracle very well, but I suppose you could do something like

```
WHERE YEAR(SHIPPEDDATE) = 2004 and MONTH(SHIPPEDDATE) = 5
```

Or, as in Gordon Linoff's answer

```
WHERE SHIPPEDDATE >= DATE '2004-05-01' AND SHIPPEDDATE < DATE '2004-06-01'
```

Comment: This is why I am confused. There is no product ID, there is a "ProductCode" but that code is only in the products table. The products table and the order table share no columns to join on.

Comment: @Kleigh - is there a third table that joins them, like ORDERITEMS or ORDERPRODUCTS?

Comment: You have no ProductCode in the orders table?

Comment: @AlexPoole, sounds like what we're looking for!

Comment: AH! yes, sorry. I have an order details table that has the product code and the quantity ordered

Comment: @jarlh - yes... also for Oracle you could do `extract(year from shippeddate) = 2004` etc., but Gordon's range allows indexes to be used.

Comment: ok, now that we know I have an orders details table, can you all amend your original answer to account for this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting an SQL command not properly ended error with that. I copied and pasted your code so there wouldn't be typos

Comment: @Kleigh - that's because of the `AS` keywords that were in there; other databases allow them, but Oracle does not for table aliases.

Answer (score 3):

The query you want looks something like this:

```
SELECT p.PRODUCTNAME, COUNT(*)
FROM ORDERS o JOIN
     PRODUCTS p
     ON o.PRODUCTID = p.PRODUCTID
WHERE o.SHIPPEDDATE >= DATE '2004-05-01' AND SHIPPEDDATE < DATE '2004-06-01'
GROUP BY p.PRODUCTNAME;
```

Notes:

- Learn to use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use `JOIN`.
- For date comparisons, use the  built-in functions and operators for dates.  Don't convert to strings unnecessarily.
- My preference for date constants is the ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD format, rather than Oracle's default format.
- You need aggregation, but leave extra columns out of the `SELECT`.